# The application has failed to start because its side-by-side configuration is incorrect

Tags: c#, asp.net, c++

On one server, everything works.
I am attempting to call a C++ assembly from C#/ASP.NET application.

When I deploy the web application in another server, it fails with the error message:
"The application has failed to start because its side-by-side configuration is incorrect"

I have copied the dll into the correct folder which has permissions for the user and the application pool identity.
The path has been added in the PATH variable.
The DLL is fine and is not dependent on any other DLL.

What could cause this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved.

Solution is to build the project in Release Mode and then deploy DLL of the release mode.